# Название ОЭЗ надо писать в кавычках или без?

Tags: названия, кавычки

Тут понятно — нужны кавычки: *В конце прошлого года в Псковской области открыли особую экономическую зону «Моглино»*.

А тут нужны: **Однако резидентов в Моглино пока всего девять**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы говорите о деревне Моглино, то **в Моглино**, еще лучше **в Моглине**, а если речь идет об экономической зоне "Моглино" — то **в "Моглино"**. Говоря о резидентах экономической зоны, правильнее называть их **резидентами "Моглино"**, а **"резиденты в Моглино"** — это, скорее всего, о резидентах, расположенных в деревне Моглино.

Comment: Речь не о деревне, а о ОЭЗ. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я бы не был так категоричен. ОЭЗ "Моглино" расположена на территории деревни Моглино.

Comment: Это мне известно. Но я знаю контекст. И в тексте речь (и в этом предложении) конкретно о самой экономической зоне.

Comment: Я понимаю текст так: В населенном пункте Моглино есть только 9 резидентов одноименной ОЭЗ.

Comment: Нет, в данном случае речь о другом: В ОЭЗ "Моглино" 9 резидентов. Только слова "ОЭЗ" потом в тексте откидываются, и автор пишет просто "Моглино" (без аббревиатуры "ОЭЗ"). Это журналистский текст. В СМИ все по-разному пишут. Автор в тексте пишет исключительно про саму ОЭЗ (особую экономическую зону), о самой деревне вообще речи не идет. ОЭЗ - это не есть сама деревня, это небольшой участок территории с особым статусом, на котором работают инвесторы и получают бонусы в виде отсутствия налогов. У меня сомнения: писать в кавычках или нет это слово, учитывая, что речь именно об ОЭЗ, а не о деревне.

Comment: Я думаю,  писать в кавычках всегда правильно.Без кавычек  - может и не ошибка, но это спорно.